# Excel VBA - Check if data in a range already exists before copying

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file with several sheets. On one sheet 'Daily Tracker' I have some data on the page that in my code I labeled this range as 'DailyTable' that contains the data I'm wanting to copy.

Once the data is filled completely for the week, I am wanting to have several things happen.

1. Data in 'DailyTable' copied to 'Daily Backup' under the last row of data. [I have this working]
2. Before 'DailyTable' is copied, it checks for duplicate data [prevent pressing the backup macro more than once and having duplicate data.]
3. If data is duplicated, a notice letting the user know they've already backed the data up for this week.
4. I'll have another script the clears the data, ticks the week # up by 1. You see some of the variables input here as I was testing this process earlier. If there is a better way of doing this, would love to hear thoughts.

My first VBA script (Please point out anything that is inefficient or that might be better done a different way, I'm very open to learning how and why things work) :

```
Sub BackupTable()

     Dim DailyWS As Worksheet
     Dim DailyTable As Range
     Dim BackupWS As Worksheet
     Dim NewTable As Range
     Dim Week As Range
     Dim WeekBackup As Range
     Dim WeekCurrent As String
     Dim WeekNext As String
     Dim NextRow As Long

     Set BackupWS = Worksheets("Daily Backup")
     Set DailyWS = Worksheets("Daily Tracker")
     Set DailyTable = DailyWS.Range("C7:Q21")
     Set Week = DailyWS.Range("F4")
     WeekNext = Week.Value + 1
     NextRow = BackupWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row
     Set WeekBackup = BackupWS.Range("A1").Offset(RowOffSet:=NextRow, ColumnOffset:=0)
     Set NewTable = BackupWS.Range("C1:Q15").Offset(RowOffSet:=NextRow, ColumnOffset:=0)

     WeekBackup.Value = Week.Value
     NewTable.Value = DailyTable.Value

     Increases Daily Table Week # by 1.

     Week = WeekNext

End Sub
```

I'm sure this looks horrible, but any help would be appreciated. Eager to learn.

============================================================================

**Edit 2/15:** I've split it into two subroutines, because I'd like to do a backup only string of questions and a backup and clear string of questions.

```
Sub ClearDailySheet()
    'Declare the variable ranges.
    Dim tB As Workbook
    Dim DailyWS As Worksheet
    Dim DailyTable As Range
    Dim BackupWS As Worksheet
    Dim NewTable As Range
    Dim Oldtable As Range
    Dim Week As Range
    Dim LastWeek As Range
    Dim WeekBackup As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim NextRow As Long

    Set tB = ThisWorkbook
    With tB
        Set BackupWS = .Sheets("Daily Tracker Backup")
        Set DailyWS = .Sheets("Daily Tracker")
    End With 'tB
    With DailyWS
        Set DailyTable = .Range("C7:Q21")
        Set Week = .Range("F4")
    End With 'DailyWS
    With BackupWS
        NextRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set WeekBackup = .Range("A1").Offset(NextRow, 0)
        Set NewTable = .Range("C1:Q15").Offset(NextRow, 0)
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        Set LastWeek = .Range("A1").Offset(LastRow, 0)
        Set Oldtable = .Range("C1:Q15").Offset(LastRow, 0)
    End With 'BackupWS

    If LastWeek.Value <> Week.Value Then
        '''Normal backup
        If vbYes <> MsgBox("Oops! Your daily tracker data for this week has not yet been backed up," & vbCrLf & _
                            "before resetting this form we recommend backing up your data. Proceed with backup? [RECOMMENDED]", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
                            "Missing Backup") Then
            '''Avoid backing up now
            MsgBox "It is NOT recommended to reset the daily sheet without backing up this week's data.", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
        Else
            '''Transfer the data
                WeekBackup.Value = Week.Value
                NewTable.Value = DailyTable.Value

                '''Notify User Backup Complete.
                MsgBox "Backup: COMPLETED [Week #" & Week.Value & "]", vbInformation + vbOKOnly

                '''Confirm Clear Data
            If vbNo <> MsgBox("Reset Daily Tracker [Clear Current Data]" & vbCrLf & _
                         "" & vbCrLf & _
                         "Are you SURE you want to reset the daily tracker?" & vbCrLf & _
                         "This canNOT be undone!", _
                         vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Confirm Daily Data Reset") Then

                '''Clear input form
                Clear_InputForm DailyWS

                '''Increases Daily Table Week # by 1 after reset.
                Week.Value = Week.Value + 1

                '''Notify User Backup Complete.
                MsgBox "Backup & Data Reset: COMPLETED!" & vbCrLf & _
                         "" & vbCrLf & _
                         "[Daily Tracker is ready for the new week!]", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
            Else
                '''What to do if they don't want to overwrite?
                MsgBox "Data Reset CANCELLED", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Else
        '''Data already present
        If vbYes <> MsgBox("This weeks tracker data (week #" & Week.Value & ") appears to be backed up already," & vbCrLf & _
                    "do you want to overwrite the old backup with the latest data before resetting the tracker? [RECOMENDED]", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
                    "Backup Data Exists") Then
            '''What to do if they don't want to overwrite?
            MsgBox "Backup & Data Reset: CANCELLED!", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly
        Else
            '''Overwrite backup
            Oldtable.Value = DailyTable.Value

            MsgBox "Backup Overwrite: COMPLETED [Week #" & Week.Value & "]", vbInformation + vbOKOnly

            '''Confirm Clear Data
            If vbNo <> MsgBox("Reset Daily Tracker [Clear Current Data]" & vbCrLf & _
                         "" & vbCrLf & _
                         "Are you SURE you want to reset the daily tracker?" & vbCrLf & _
                         "This canNOT be undone!", _
                         vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Confirm Daily Data Reset") Then

            '''Clear input form
            Clear_InputForm DailyWS

            '''Increases Daily Table Week # by 1 after reset.
            Week.Value = Week.Value + 1

            '''Notify User Backup Complete.
                MsgBox "Backup & Data Reset: COMPLETED!" & vbCrLf & _
                         "" & vbCrLf & _
                         "[Daily Tracker is ready for the new week!]", vbInformation + vbOKOnly

            Else
            '''What to do if they don't want to overwrite?
            MsgBox "Data Reset: CANCELLED!", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly

            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Clear_InputForm(SheetToClean As Worksheet)
    '''Actual Range
    SheetToClean.Range("D8:L8,N8,O8,P8,Q8,D13:D19,F13:I19,K13:Q19").Select
    '''Test Range
    'SheetToClean.Range("D31,F31,G31,H31,I31,K31,L31,M31,N31,O31,P31,Q31").ClearContents

End Sub

Sub BackupData()
    'Declare the variable ranges.
    Dim tB As Workbook
    Dim DailyWS As Worksheet
    Dim DailyTable As Range
    Dim BackupWS As Worksheet
    Dim NewTable As Range
    Dim Oldtable As Range
    Dim Week As Range
    Dim LastWeek As Range
    Dim WeekBackup As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim NextRow As Long

    Set tB = ThisWorkbook
    With tB
        Set BackupWS = .Sheets("Daily Tracker Backup")
        Set DailyWS = .Sheets("Daily Tracker")
    End With 'tB
    With DailyWS
        Set DailyTable = .Range("C7:Q21")
        Set Week = .Range("F4")
    End With 'DailyWS
    With BackupWS
        NextRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set WeekBackup = .Range("A1").Offset(NextRow, 0)
        Set NewTable = .Range("C1:Q15").Offset(NextRow, 0)
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        Set LastWeek = .Range("A1").Offset(LastRow, 0)
        Set Oldtable = .Range("C1:Q15").Offset(LastRow, 0)
    End With 'BackupWS

    If LastWeek.Value <> Week.Value Then
        '''Normal backup
        If vbYes <> MsgBox("Backing up your daily tracker sheet. You can do this anytime you'd like" & vbCrLf & _
                            "throughout the week. This will simply make a backup of your daily" & vbCrLf & _
                            "data in the 'Daily Tracker Backup' tab. Do you want to proceed?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
                            "Backup Daily Tracker Data") Then
            '''Avoid backing up now
            MsgBox "BACKUP CANCELLED!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
        Else
            '''Transfer the data
                WeekBackup.Value = Week.Value
                NewTable.Value = DailyTable.Value

                '''Notify User Backup Complete.
                MsgBox "BACKUP SUCCESSFUL: Week #" & Week, vbInformation + vbOKOnly
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Else

        '''Data already present
        If vbYes <> MsgBox("This weeks daily data (Week #" & Week.Value & ") is already backedup," & vbCrLf & _
                    "do you want to update this backup [overwrite it]?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
                    "Backup Data Exists") Then
            '''What to do if they don't want to overwrite?
            MsgBox "BACKUP CANCELLED!", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
            Exit Sub
        Else

            '''Overwrite backup
            Oldtable.Value = DailyTable.Value

            MsgBox "BACKUP OVEWRITE SUCCESSFUL: Week #" & Week.Value, vbInformation + vbOKOnly

            End If
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Take a minute to take the tour : http://stackoverflow.com/tour . And see this example to find the last used cell in a column : http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/918/methods-for-finding-the-last-used-row-or-column-in-a-worksheet/3043/find-the-last-non-empty-cell-in-a-column#t=201702030956275513223 BTW, not bad for a first script! ;)

Comment: Just copy and paste plain then apply `RemoveDuplicates` method of the `Range` Object in the back-up sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WeekNext` wasn't useful and `WeekCurrent` wasn't used, so I commented them.

I've added some `With` to show how useful it can be (and it increase performance a bit).

And when you can, use the Excel built-in functions that will be more efficient (like `RemoveDuplicates`)!

```
Sub BackupTable()
    Dim tB As Workbook
    Dim DailyWS As Worksheet
    Dim DailyTable As Range
    Dim BackupWS As Worksheet
    Dim NewTable As Range
    Dim Week As Range
    Dim WeekBackup As Range
    'Dim WeekCurrent As String
    'Dim WeekNext As String
    Dim NextRow As Long

    Set tB = ThisWorkbook
    With tB
        Set BackupWS = .Sheets("Daily Backup")
        Set DailyWS = .Sheets("Daily Tracker")
    End With 'tB
    With DailyWS
        Set DailyTable = .Range("C7:Q21")
        Set Week = .Range("F4")
    End With 'DailyWS
    With BackupWS
        NextRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set WeekBackup = .Range("A1").Offset(NextRow, 0)
        Set NewTable = .Range("C1:Q15").Offset(NextRow, 0)
    End With 'BackupWS

    '''Transfer the data
    WeekBackup.Value = Week.Value
    NewTable.Value = DailyTable.Value

    '''Apply RemoveDuplicates (2 parameters):
    '''(the array tells which columns it should take into accout to detect duplicates)
    '''(xlGuess let excel guess if you have Headers, or set it to xlYes or xlNo)
    Call BackupWS.UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17), xlGuess)

    '''Increases Daily Table Week # by 1.
    Week.Value = Week.Value + 1
End Sub
```

---

With a few changes to select overwrite or not (I combined both subs) :

```
    'Declare the variable ranges.
    Dim tB As Workbook
    Dim DailyWS As Worksheet
    Dim DailyTable As Range
    Dim BackupWS As Worksheet
    Dim NewTable As Range
    Dim Oldtable As Range
    Dim Week As Range
    Dim LastWeek As Range
    Dim WeekBackup As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim NextRow As Long

    Set tB = ThisWorkbook
    With tB
        Set BackupWS = .Sheets("Daily Tracker Backup")
        Set DailyWS = .Sheets("Daily Tracker")
    End With 'tB
    With DailyWS
        Set DailyTable = .Range("C7:Q21")
        Set Week = .Range("F4")
    End With 'DailyWS
    With BackupWS
        NextRow = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set WeekBackup = .Range("A1").Offset(NextRow, 0)
        Set NewTable = .Range("C1:Q15").Offset(NextRow, 0)
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        Set LastWeek = .Range("A1").Offset(LastRow, 0)
        Set Oldtable = .Range("C1:Q15").Offset(LastRow, 0)
    End With 'BackupWS

    If LastWeek.Value <> Week.Value Then
        '''Normal backup
        If vbYes <> MsgBox("Your daily tracker data has not been backed up," & vbCrLf & _
                            "do you want to backup your data up now?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
                            "Missing Backup for this Week") Then
            '''Avoid backing up now
            Exit Sub
        Else
            '''Confirm Clear Data
            If vbNo <> MsgBox("This will reset this section." & vbCrLf & _
                            "Are you SURE you want to reset your daily data sheet?" & vbCrLf & _
                            "This canNOT be undone!", _
                            vbYesNo + vbCritical, "Confirm Daily Data Wipe") Then
                '''Transfer the data
                WeekBackup.Value = Week.Value
                NewTable.Value = DailyTable.Value

                '''Clear input form
                Clear_InputForm DailyWS

                '''Increases Daily Table Week # by 1 after reset.
                Week.Value = Week.Value + 1
                '''Notify User Backup Complete.
                MsgBox "BACKUP COMPLETE: Week #" & Week, vbInformation + vbOKOnly
            Else
                '''What to do if they don't want to overwrite?
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Else
        '''Data already present
        If vbYes <> MsgBox("This weeks (" & Week.Value & ") daily data appears to be backedup already," & vbCrLf & _
                    "do you want to overwrite the existing backup?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, _
                    "Backup Data Exists") Then
            '''What to do if they don't want to overwrite?
            Exit Sub
        Else
            '''Overwrite backup
            Oldtable.Value = DailyTable.Value

            '''Clear input form
            Clear_InputForm DailyWS

            MsgBox "BACKUP OVEWRITE COMPLETE: Week #" & Week.Value, vbInformation + vbOKOnly
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

And the sub to clear the form (can only be called from the same module as it is private) :

```
Private Sub Clear_InputForm(SheetToClean As Worksheet)
    '''Actual Range (avoid using select which is slow)
    'SheetToClean.Range("D8:L8,N8,O8,P8,Q8,D13:D19,F13:I19,K13:Q19").ClearContents
    '''Test Range (use select to see which range you are gonna clear)
    SheetToClean.Range("D31,F31,G31,H31,I31,K31,L31,M31,N31,O31,P31,Q31").Select
    'Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: Great, I can clearly see how `with` works in your example.

I'll take a look at the `call` function...I do wonder...will this check if there are duplicates or will it simply copy then remove any duplicates?

What I'm needing it to do is check to see if the data in the current table matches the last entry on the backup sheet.

Comment: I'll come back later on the `Call` (1AM here!^^). That doesn't check if the data is the same! What to do if only it is different ? And if not? (I'll edit to reflect that) !)

Comment: No problem! Sleep! So....push button. Checks to see if data set is already present [maybe we can simplify this by seeing if the Week # is already present. Comment out the week + 1, it'll be under a separate sub anyways. So when you process BackupTable(), so it'll be a lot simpler than having it check the whole range of data for a duplicate on the backup page we can have it check the week count rows on the backup page. If it exists, it errors saying this week Is already backed up. Do you want to overwrite it?" If yes, it will overwrite the range with the new data, if not then it will cancel.

Comment: I can then use the same code to check the backup data when clearing the daily sheet for the new week, and prompt the user to backup the data if it is missing.

Comment: Just checking if you had any thoughts on this @R3uk. If not, no problem!

Comment: I added what I have so far.

Comment: @BetaOp9 : Sry for the delay, I'm still a bit busy but I'll take a look at this in a few hours! ;)

Comment: Not problem! I do appreciate your time to look into this. I hope what I've added make sense. Please let me know if it doesn't. It's 5AM here so going to bed.

Comment: @BetaOp9 : Finally done! ;) I've added a few things (improved MsgBox, details in comments, ...). But you were definitely on the right path! ;)

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! Looks much cleaner. One thing I did notice, if the data already exists and you tell it to overwrite the data...it doesn't move on to clearing the data once it's done overwriting the backup data. Is there a way to get it to go to the clear data section of the code once the overwrite is complete?

Comment: I also notice if I the backup is not already there, if I say yes to backing up the data and then no to clearing the daily tracker that it doesn't back up the data.

Comment: @BetaOp9 : Yup, I forgot to clear the form after overwrite, I edited to put the form reset in a separate sub, I'll let you try that. There are commentaries in each case of the `If`s and there is 2 with **'''What to do if they don't want to overwrite?** which are the cases where you'll need to decide if there is something to do! I see that you haven't take the tour yet : http://stackoverflow.com/tour please take a minute to discover how SO works! And then I think it'll be time to accept my answer! (and upvote it, if you feel like it! ;) )

Comment: Awesome work. You solved a lot of problems and helped clean up my logic. The comments helped a lot as well. I updated my original thread to reflect my last round of changes if you want to give it one last lookover. I also gave you credit for the answer and followed the tour link you provided. Thanks!

Comment: If I wanted to post up my full finished script up once it's done to have the community look over and give feedback on how viable it is, would that be allowed to post?

Comment: @BetaOp9 : You can post it here, or better, on www.codereview.stackexchange.com ;)